# Select many box for HABTM

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have two models; question and category which have a HABTM association between them. Now I want to have a form where I can edit the questions categories, however I don't know how. I started with this but I am lost, I am unsure on what to name the "name" attributes etc and how it is automatically edited/created with the question, how do I set this up?

```
<%= f.fields_for :categories do |categories_form| %>
        <%= categories_form.select "category_ids", Category.all.collect { |c| [c.description, c.id] }, {}, {:multiple => true, :size => 9} %>
    <% end %>
```

I managed to set up question(has_many) --> answer with fields_for and accepts_nested_attributes_for, but not this.

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at the following screencasts by Ryan Bates [Nested Model Form Part 1](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1) and [Nested Model Form Part 2](http://railscasts.com/episodes/197-nested-model-form-part-2).

Answer (score 0):

**Migrations**

You need to create the migrations for the tables

You need to create the migration for the middle table of the association
+ the middle table name that is created by the association is :categories_questions
or :questions_categories, in the second case you must define the name in models as shown in the link 
[Do I need to manually create a migration for a HABTM join table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/564306/do-i-need-to-manually-create-a-migration-for-a-habtm-join-table)

```
class CreateCategoriesQuestions < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :categories_questions, :id => false do |t|
        t.references :category
        t.references :question
    end
    add_index :categories_questions, [:category_id, :question_id]
    add_index :categories_questions, [:question_id, :category_id]
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :categories_questions
  end
end
```

**Question Model**

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :categories
end
```

**Category Model**

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :questions
end
```

**Controller Stuf**

**questions_controller.rb**

```
def new
  @question = Question.new
  @question.categories.build #Build a categories_questions so as to use fields_for 
end
```

**Form Stuff**

```
= f.fields_for :categories do |categories_fields|
  = categories_fields.text_field :name
  = categories_fields.text_field :description
```

At this point i must tell you ( i am new in ruby & rails ) that to create a new object here you can use jquery to append a html block name properly, or create helpers (that use javascript in the end) to add a new object and on save, save the association.
In the next link someone demonstrated the exact way .

http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/fields_for#512-Setting-child-index-while-using-nested-attributes-mass-assignment